# Errors in opscenterd.log after starting repair service

Tags: datastax-enterprise, opscenter, datastax-startup

After upgrading from Opscenter 5.x > 6.0.8 > 6.1.0 > 6.1.1, I see lots of errors and warnings in the opscenterd.log, like the following. I'm using DSE 4.8.10. I've turned on the Repair Service, which seems to be working as expected. But I see WARNings in the log. Are these anything to be concerned about?

```
2017-06-27 01:00:00,356 [local] ERROR: The best practice rule 'Tombstone count' has failed. (MainThread)
2017-06-27 01:00:00,358 [local] ERROR: The best practice rule 'Wide partitions' has failed. (MainThread)
2017-06-27 01:00:00,451 [local] ERROR: The best practice rule 'Secondary indexes cardinality' has failed. (MainThread)
2017-06-27 13:10:11,672 [opscenterd]  WARN: Unknown request 54688d7f-7c5f-4bcb-bc4d-07b7a0a79c3c (running {'started': 1498569009, 'details': u'Repair session f260e7b0-5b39-11e7-87cf-612516369059 for range (1042910172352712044,1065269862139026652] finished', 'details-type': None}) (MainThread)
2017-06-27 13:12:40,885 [opscenterd]  WARN: Unknown request 341c9bc9-1c00-4771-aa64-27206ad4152a (running {'started': 1498569160, 'details': u'Repair session 4c3d5c50-5b3a-11e7-87cf-612516369059 for range (-1555782662812296764,-1538702344225528661] finished', 'details-type': None}) (MainThread)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpsCenter is warning about repair sessions on the Cassandra nodes that it doesn't recognize. They could be sessions that are hung up; there are a number of tickets related to that in Cassandra 2.1.x and older:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10012
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10992
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10961
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-12901

You could try to clean up these sessions by invoking `forceTerminateAllRepairSessions` via JMX on the StorageSession mbean. Or, a rolling restart on the cluster should do the trick.

Regardless, OpsCenter's Repair Service will operate normally.